# Когда слово "наконец" является вводным?

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

Насколько мне известно, слово "наконец" может выступать в качестве вводного слова и, следовательно, выделяется запятой.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, при каких условиях "наконец" — это вводное слово.

Answer (score 2):

Слово "наконец" является вводным, если подытоживает сказанное. (Т.е. раньше было явное или скрытое "во-первых", "во-вторых", "в-третьих" и "наконец".)
Вводное слово "наконец" бывает очень сложно отличить от обстоятельства "наконец".  В таком случае возможна замена на "наконец-то". (Наконец он пришёл.)

Answer (score 1):

Слово НАКОНЕЦ является вводным только в том случае, когда не имеет пространственного или временного значения, а указывает порядок мыслей. Например:
*Надеюсь, что в ближайшее время этот проект наконец будет реализован. И, наконец, последнее, на что хотелось бы обратить внимание*.

(gramota.ru)