# Нужна ли запятая после слова "наконец"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова

Знаю, что если "наконец" в значении "наконец-то", то запятая не нужна. Но никак не могу понять нужна ли  вот в таких случаях запятая:

> "Ты уйдёшь наконец или нет?"

или

> "Да заправишь ты наконец постель?"

Comment: См. также: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/34363/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%86-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f

Comment: См. также: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/2788/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%86-%d1%8f%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc/2802#2802

Answer (score 3):

1) **Наречие времени  в реальной ситуации** (здесь можно заменить наречием *наконец-то*)

Он долго молчал, наконец заговорил. Я прислушался и наконец услышал стук. Мы долго гуляли, наконец устали и пошли домой.  Долгами жил его отец, Давал три бала ежегодно И промотался наконец (Пушкин).

2) **Вводное слово** (заключительное слово в перечне или выражение нетерпения)

Ещё не все потеряно; наконец, у нас есть и другие возможности. Сядьте у камина, перечтите что-нибудь легкое, выпейте, наконец, вина. Перестань, наконец, шуметь!

3) **Наконец-то!** Восклицание, выражающее удовлетворение по поводу осуществления чего-л. Наконец-то начался отпуск! Наконец-то я достала эту книгу!

Answer (score 2):

"Ты уйдёшь, наконец, или нет?"- нетерпение,оценка факта - вводное.

"Да заправишь ты, наконец, постель?" -то же самое, нетерпение, оценка факта с точки зрения говорящего - вводное, выделяем запятыми.

Не является вводным в значении "под конец","напоследок","после всего", часто при перечислении: это, это и наконец это.